# Remove sheet protection only

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that protects the workbook that is three stages: eliminating protection, run macros, and protection again.

If the customer chooses another password manually, (he must know the password of the code) the protection cancellation code no longer works

How can I disable the option of canceling protection, so you can cancel protection only with code, to prevent changes if the password?

Comment: You can't. The user who knows the password can always use it to unprotect the workbook or worksheet. But have a look at the `UserInterfaceOnly` parameter of the [Worksheet.Protect Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect). If you use this you don't have to unprotect your worksheet everytime you run a macro on it. It only protects the sheet from user manipulation but not VBA.

Comment: I've seen codes that disable buttons in Excel like copying, there's no similar way to a sheet protection button?

Comment: Even if you can do that, the user can easily enable that button too. It would be easier not to tell users the password, so they can *not* unprotect and reprotect your sheet with another password.

Answer (score 0):

You can protect a VBA project to prevent a user from seeing the code and then code in a password prior to execution of the rest of the code (Tools > VBA Project Properties)

```
Dim password As Variant
pword = Application.InputBox("Please enter password", "Enter Password")

Select Case pword
    Case Is = "superstrongpassword"
        'insert code or maybe a GoTo statement?
    Case Else
        msgbox("Incorrect password")
        Exit sub
End Select
```

GoTo statements can make code difficult to read and debug, but in this instance it seems like a straightforward usage.

Hope it helps.